# WordPress: Getting title of post with ID

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have an `ACF relationship field` called `van_range_type`.

`van_range_type` shows posts from the `range` `custom post type`. In this post type, I have three posts which have the following IDs

- Range 1 (`ID: 116`)
- Range 2 (`ID: 163`)
- Range 3 (`ID: 164`)

I have another post type called `campers`. In this post type, a `van_range_type` must be selected from the `relationship field` (idea being that a camper belongs to a range).

In one of my posts in `campers`, I have defined the relationship field as `Range 2`. in this camper post, I am not trying to get the title of the range. I.e. I'm trying to assign a variable called `$range_name` which, in this scenario, should have the value of `Range 2`.

To do this, I have done the following:

```html
$range_type_id = get_field('van_range_type');
var_dump($range_type_id); // this returns 163

if($range_type_id):
  $range_name = get_the_title($range_type_id);
endif;

var_dump($range_name); // this returns an empty string
```

However, `$range_name` returns an empty string? I have seen similar questions before (i.e. [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125729/how-to-get-page-title-with-the-page-id)), but the approach isn't working for me?

Comment: Can’t see why this should not work, at a glance. Your custom post type _is_ using the standard WP `title` feature, yes? (It would be rather unlikely, but it could be disabled via the `supports` parameter in the CPT setup, and the `Range X` could be stored in some other custom field.)

Comment: What happens when you change the return format in your ACF field configuration from ID to post? If you then dump what get_field returned, do you see the `title` property set as it should be in the returned WP_Post instance?

Comment: Hi @CBroe - When I change the return format of the `relationship` field from `id` to `object` and then `var_dump($range_name)`, I do see `post_title` return the correct `title`. Unsure why it's behaviour is different when the format is `id`?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
if($range_type_id != 0):
  $range_name = get_the_title($range_type_id);
endif;
```

or

```
if($range_type_id != ''):
  $range_name = get_the_title($range_type_id);
endif;
```

Comment: As a general side note, if the code inside the if block is a single line you don't need to use brackets or `:` `endif`, you can simply do `if (condition) // single line code;`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast you're right, it is possible to omit those but not recommended by the PSR standards (see https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/ ) because it can introduce errors if you add one line into the condition for example

Comment: Hi Drashti, I can confirm, I've tried both of the above and neither work. When I do a `var_dump($range_name)`, it returns `string(0) ""` on both occasions.

Comment: Hi @Freddy are you sure you have inserted titles in all the posts?
and titles are stored in default title field of posts ?
also check this
print_r( get_post($range_type_id) );

Comment: @DrashtiRajpura - Yup, can confirm they all have titles. My `van_range_type` `relationship` field currently has its `return_format` set to `id`. When I changed this to `object` and do a `var_dump`, it prints the correct title in `post_title`.  When I run `print_r( get_post($range_type_id) ); ` it doesn't print anything

Comment: Okay so then can you get an object instead of ID and get post_title from that? @Freddy